# Возможно ли с помощью sys.stdout.write("\r") редактировать первую строку терминала не изменяя другие?

Tags: python

Вот мой код:

```
import time
import sys
import psutil
import threading
from random import randint
def sysusage():
    while True:
        mem=dict(psutil.virtual_memory()._asdict())["percent"]
        cpu=psutil.cpu_percent()
        sys.stdout.write("\r")
        sys.stdout.write(f"[CPU:{cpu}%    RAM:{mem}%]") 
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)

sysuse = threading.Thread(target=sysusage,daemon=True)
sysuse.start()
while 1==1:
    print(f"{randint(100,999)}")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Выход:

```
649
[CPU:0.0%    RAM:92.2%]172
698
[CPU:16.7%    RAM:92.3%]600
109
[CPU:11.5%    RAM:92.3%]741
539
```

хотя строчка `[CPU:11.5%    RAM:92.3%]` должна была остаться сверху и обновляться:

```
[CPU:11.5%    RAM:92.3%]
649
172
698
600
109
741
539
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я решил эту проблему с помощью библиотеки asciimatics
`pip install asciimatics`

```py
from asciimatics.screen import Screen
from time import sleep
import time
import os
import sys
import psutil
import threading
from random import randint
line=1
def demo(screen):
    global line

    while True:
        mem=dict(psutil.virtual_memory()._asdict())["percent"]
        cpu=psutil.cpu_percent()
        screen.print_at(f"\r"*20, 0, 0,bg=6)
        screen.print_at(f"[CPU:{cpu}%    RAM:{mem}%]   ", 0, 0,bg=6)
        screen.print_at(f"{randint(100,999)}", 0, line,bg=6)
        line+=1
        if line > 20:
            line=1
        screen.refresh()
        time.sleep(1)

    sysuse = threading.Thread(target=demo,daemon=True)
    sysuse.start()

Screen.wrapper(demo)
```

Теперь вывод программы выглядит как нужно.

Answer (score 1):

В конце кода, где вывод случайного числа, по дефолту print добавляет перенос строки ("\n").

Хотя даже если написать `print("...", end="")`, то выводить что-то, и обновлять первую строку по моему не выйдет, курсор уже сместился

Comment: не об этом речь, проблема заключается не в переносе строки, а в изменении первой строки не затрагивая последующие